# Unable to find module file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC120_MFCLOC_x64.msm

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, missing-data, merge-module

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and am trying to build a solution in it. When building the solution I get the error: `Unable to find module file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC120_MFCLOC_x64.msm`. I have searched online and googled quite a bit but I can not find a place where I could download this `.msm` module. Moreover, when I navigate to the `Common files` folder, I seem to find no Merge Modules folder. So my questions would be:

- Where can I acquire the missing module?
- Is it normal to not have the 'Merge Modules' folder (my VS2019 installation was perfectly fine)?

Comment: Getting the merge modules is an install option that is off by default.  Run Visual Studio Installer > Modify > Individual components > tick "C++ 2019 Redistributable MSMs".  Do beware that "VC120" is the version number of VS2013, you do need to update to the VS2019 version (143).

Comment: @HansPassant  And are there other ways to get the modules if I'm unable to update them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so as pointed out by @HansPassant the module is from 2013 version of VS. So I downloaded the VS2013 and acquired the `Common Files/Merge Modules`. The module that I was looking for was there. Then I built the solution and everything worked fine.